# Problem with graphics package after update MikTeX: File `pdftex.def' not found

Tags: graphics

After update of MikTeX compilation stops with the following error:

```
File `pdftex.def' not found. ...ed{ver@\Gin@driver}{\input{\Gin@driver}}{}.
```

Comment: While the snippet you post looks like you are experiencing a problem, it is hard for others to diagnose without more information. In the *TeX world, a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) is often needed in order for others to provide meaningful help.

Comment: Try to install  this package manually from some internet repository by help of MikTeX Package Manager .

Comment: Your local package database is not uptodate. Sychnronize (package manager admin+user, menu repository).

Answer (score 6):

I had this exact same problem. After I updated, I notice that "graphics-def" was uninstalled somehow! Installing this again will fix the problem.

Comment: How install graphics-def ?

Comment: Use Miktex package manager.

Comment: This package doesn't seem to be available before Fedora 25...  However, there is a package called "pdftex-def".   :)  (in the "texlive-" distribution.)